# How I download all my files from Drafts for iPhone?

Tags: ios, applications, data-transfer

I made a lot of notes in [Drafts](http://agiletortoise.com/drafts/) and now want to have it on my Mac.

I have access to app by PhoneView but still can't find any text files. Also tried to contact the developer - no response.

Comment: I don't want to download one by one 100+ files :/

Answer (score 1):

Directly in the page you linked it's stated:

> **Flexible Output**
>
> Send tweets to Twitter, post to Facebook, compose and send email, SMS/Messages, create calendar events – or save drafts to Dropbox or Evernote

So you could just send these notes of yours through email or Dropbox, for instance.

Comment: I want download them all at once and this seems to be impossible